# javascript: get attribute value with space

Tags: javascript, dom, getattribute

when I do this `elm.getAttribute('class')`, it seems to return the value without any spaces that follows it.

for example, `<a class="special ">`, it will return `"special"`. I would like the returned value to be `"special "`

Comment: Why do you need that?

Comment: @C-linkNepal I generate an xpath with `[@class="special"]` will not select element with space in it.

Comment: It's already returning `"special "`. [example](http://jsfiddle.net/w9pt0x7p/)

Comment: @example it is not including the white space in chrome

Comment: @user299709 please specify on which browser/platform you're seeing this.

Comment: The fiddle I provided shows the space in my Chrome 37 ... How do you test the value? `console.log(elm.getAttribute('class'))` ? `console.log(JSON.stringify(elm.getAttribute('class')))` ?

Comment: It shows with space in chrome too.

Answer (score 2):

The [*class*](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/dom.html#classes) attribute represents a set of [*space separated tokens*](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/infrastructure.html#set-of-space-separated-tokens), where leading and trailing whitespace, and any number of intermediate whitespace characters, is allowed.

There was a time when some browsers retained whitespace in the attribute exactly as it was assigned, and some didn't. It was also common for any leading or trailing whitespace in the class attribute value to be removed, and intermediate whitespace to be kept to a single character, regardless of the actual value set.

However, testing in current Safari, Chrome, Camino and Firefox shows that trailing whitespace is retained when using `...getAttribute('class')`, however I would not depend on that.